# Using dict.fromkey() to initialize dictionary of lists results in strange .append() behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to initialize a Python dictionary of 12 keys, all set to empty lists to later populate with different values. Here is a simplified example of the issue

The naive solution returns the desired results but it's unpleasant to see a large body of code:

```
output = {
    'a': [],
    'b': [],
    'c': []
}

output['a'].append(1)
output['b'].append(2)
output['c'].append(3)

print(output)
```

> {'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [3]}

However, when I attempt to create the dictionary via dict.fromkeys():

```
output = dict.fromkeys(('a', 'b', 'c'), [])

output['a'].append(1)
output['b'].append(2)
output['c'].append(3)

print(output)
```

> {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}

Prior to appending, both methods return the same results - a dictionary of empty lists so I'm confused why the appending behavior is different. Please let me know if more information is needed

Comment: it's the same list in each key

Comment: This is a case where you need `output = {x:[] for x in ('a', 'b', 'c')}`

Comment: The documentation for [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) says: "All of the values refer to just a single instance, so it generally doesn’t make sense for value to be a mutable object such as an empty list. To get distinct values, use a dict comprehension instead."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your dictionary entries will reference the same list instance.  So there is actually only one list.

In order to get distinct lists, you cannot use the `fomkeys()` method but a dictionary comprehension would work (because every iteration will create a distinct instance of the list):

```
output = {k:[] for k in ('a','b','c')}
```